# Code First - How to programatically generate DbContext and Entities?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

So, following this example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542) I was able to manually type out the Entity classes and DbContext class in order to create a new database from scratch.

That is all well and good, but, I need to programmatically create the DbContext and Entities (from an assembly I built that provides the metadata) not manually type them out. I then need the database to be created in SQL on the fly during compile or run time, not when a record is programmatically added (as the example in the above link demonstrates).

Is this possible with the Code-First method?

Comment: So, using t4 templates I was able to include my assembly and generate the DbContext and Entity classes. The problem is I still need to programmatically open the DbContext, create a new empty entity and add it then call db.SaveChanges() in order for the database and tables to get created in SQL!! There has got to be another way to create the database!! Anyone?

Comment: Database.Initialize would create the database. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.initialize(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: That did it, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. To generate the DbContext and Entities I used T4 templates (for more on T4 templates see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx) and then simply call Database.Initialize(false) to force the database to create when the application (console application in this case) is executed.

```
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            db.Database.Initialize(false);
        }
```